# Batch Searching

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-boot, performance

I have a students table with student_id as primary key. I have a list of student_ids called idList, where size of this idList is 50000. I want to select the record from my table if student_id of that record is present in the idList. As there is a limit on IN clause of sql query and findAllById jpa method, I could not use the. My project is java17, springboot based. Please suggest a solution.

I tried using IN clause and findAllById jpa method.

Comment: Create a temp table containing the 50,000 ids you want to query, then do a join.  This is what relational databases do best.